# Setting up an array with a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This code is almost taken directly out of a book but it just doesn't seem to work, i removed the loop and just set up all the different indexes of the array with the image src etc. and it worked so i think theres something simple im doing wrong here. Can anyone see what is wrong with this snippet of code?

```
var demo = new Array();
var titleNumFrames = 7;
for(x=0; x<titleNumFrames; x++) {
    demo[x]=new Image();
    demo[x].src = “image”+x+”.jpg”;
}
```

When i said it did not work, i meant the images just weren't being preloaded and sometimes strange things would happen only when that for loop was in the code. Ended up being the quote marks, simple mistake - wont be copy  code out of word/powerpoint files in future!

Comment: You quotation marks are wrong. It should be `"` not `“`

Comment: maybe you have to declare x in/ before the loop:  for(var x=0; ........

Comment: When you say "doesn't seem to work", what's actually going wrong? Are you getting errors? Are your images not appearing (which is what I'd expect from the sample) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text editor (more like word processor) or keybindings are erroneously replacing normal quotes `"` in your code with smart quotes `“`.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Tried that after Emil Vikström suggested it and worked perfectly. Copy pasted that bit of the code out of a powerpoint slide and just did not realise the quote marks were wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the array you have is empty. I think you should use the following notation:

```
var demo = new Array();
var titleNumFrames = 7;
for(x=0; x<titleNumFrames; x++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = “image”+x+”.jpg”;
    demo.push(img);
}
```

Comment: It's for an animation, i can't use that notation afaik.